# How to know which prefab button I am clicking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a couple of prefab buttons. When I click each one of them they go to the same scene, but I that scene to have different information according to which button I clicked. How can know which was the button I clicked? The function goArtistDetail is the one being called by every button.

I have this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonScriptTwo : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Debug.Log("ButtonScriptTwo");
        Debug.Log("counter: " + GlobalState.counter);
    }

    public void goArtistDetail(Button button)
    {
        GlobalState.counter++;
        Application.LoadLevel("ArtistDetail");
    }
}
```

[Prefab of the Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJaXF.png)

Comment: Try to use 'button' parameter from goArtistDetail(Button button)

Comment: I had to remove that because it gets empty. Since the buttons are created by as a prefab they don't get assigned there

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason why you are trying to use the same method for both calls other than that the same scene is being loaded? If not why not just have a different method for each buttons onClick and set a PlayerPref.

```
public void ButtonClick_1()
{
    GoArtistDetail(1);
}

public void ButtonClick_2()
{
    GoArtistDetail(2);
}

// C# Methods start with a Captial  
private void GoArtistDetail(int refererBtn)
{
    GlobalState.counter++;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Referer Button", refererBtn)
    Application.LoadLevel("ArtistDetail");
}
```

An then in the `ArtistDetail` scene

```
private void Start()
{
    int refererBtn = 1; //Default value
    if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Referer Button"))
    {
        refererBtn = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Referer Button");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Referer Button");// Remove it if it is use once
    }

    //Evaluate refererBtn to show what info is relevant
}
```